# eslint-plugin-angular why You should prefer the factory() method instead of service()

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6, webpack

So I'm using

https://github.com/AngularClass/NG6-starter

with

https://github.com/Gillespie59/eslint-plugin-angular

I've got this simple class service

```
const auth = {
  account: 'api/account'
};

class AuthService{
  constructor($http) {
    'ngInject';

    this.http = $http;
  }
  account(){
    return this.http.get(auth.account)
    .then(function(response) {
      var account = response.data;
      return account;
    });
  }
}
export default AuthService;
```

if in the module index I do like

```
import AuthService from './auth.service';
.service('AuthService',AuthService)
```

and it seems good to me it's a class 
so I don't understand why on earth
eslint-plugin-angular point me out

**You should prefer the factory() method instead of service()**

but on the other hand I can't use a factory it's a class
not a plain object !

I don't really understand the point.
Is there anyone out of there could me explain the topic
please ? May be I miss something.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a little bit of searching found this: https://github.com/Gillespie59/eslint-plugin-angular/blob/master/docs/no-service-method.md

Comment: I'm using es6 so I should use a class as service so I can't use factory it's a no sense !

Comment: Read the [link to John Papa's item](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#style-y040) from that link I provided. He states that all factories are instantiated with the new keyword, which works for classes.

Comment: Sorry but I don't see the point I'm using es6 so why should I use a plain object take a look at http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/07/07/service-vs-factory-once-and-for-all.html  http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/07/07/service-vs-factory-once-and-for-all.html

Comment: If you're just looking to argue about it, SO is not the place. I've pointed you to the places where a justification for the rule is explained. If you don't like the rule, disable it in your lint configuration.